# Problem with content encoding and connecting with DevTools to chrome headless

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I am starting a headless chrome instance like that, e.g.

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://www.chromestatus
```

and want to connect with DevTools to this instance by entering `localhost:9222` into a running browser. However, what I see is just some garbled stuff like this here "��TQo�0~ϯ���$���li51����manri̜8�������m::�...", probably because the server process at localhost:9222 sends the response gzipped, but does not include a content-encoding in the response headers (at least, that's my theory why this happens...)

Any idea how I can fix this? I haven't found any option to control this behavior (e.g. to tell the headless chrome instance to not zip the response data...)

BTW: I see the same whether I enter the url in chrome, chromium or firefox or use wget, and also whether I use chrome (Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105) or chromium doesn't make a difference...

Comment: I am also desperate to solve the issue. The issue still persists in latest chromium beta builds. Submitted issue to google. Star the issue here - https://crbug.com/1121054